# Compile time operations on floating point types

Tags: c++, boost, clang, static-members, static-assert

I  have some static const floating point member variables, on which I want to do some compile time static asserts. The following code compiles in gcc but fails in both clang and Visual Studio:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Scalar>
class ProbModel {
public:
  static const Scalar probA;
  static const Scalar probB;

private:
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(probA < 1, "Weird Parameter");
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(probB < 1, "Weird Parameter");
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(probA < probB, "Weird Parameter");
};

// Initializations
template<typename Scalar> const Scalar
ProbModel<Scalar>::probA = 0.3;

template<typename Scalar> const Scalar
ProbModel<Scalar>::probB = 0.6;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  typedef ProbModel<float> Modelf;
  std::cout << "ProbA = " << Modelf::probA << std::endl;
}
```

I get errors in Visual Studio 2013 and Clang for the static assert statements complaing about constant expression:

```
2>..\static_assert_experiments.cpp(11): error C2057: expected constant expression
2>..\static_assert_experiments.cpp(12): error C2057: expected constant expression
2>..\static_assert_experiments.cpp(13): error C2057: expected constant expression
```

A non c++11 solution for doing this will be highly appreciated. Also is there other ways to do these kind of checks on static parameters?

Comment: I don't think there is a (portable) C++03 solution: `const` floating-point values variables cannot be used (lvalue-to-rvalue converted) in constant expressions; the variables need to have integral type.

Comment: C++03, [expr.const]/1 "An *integral constant expression* can involve only literals, enumerators, `const` variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions [...]. Floating literals can appear only if they are cast to integral or enumeration types."

Comment: Hmm. In VS12 BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(static_cast<int>(probA) == 0) is illegal but BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(static_cast<int>(0.5) == 0) works

Comment: @dyp Do you have suggestion for achieving a similar check which is portable.

Comment: As my quote says: floating *literals* (that is, values written directly in code, such as `1.1` or `0.5`) can be used in constant expressions; but not floating-point type *variables*.

Comment: Maybe this is an X-Y problem, or can be solved differently. What do you want to achieve? Currently, `probA` and `probB` are always initialized such that the asserts should fail.

Comment: I guess its a XY problem. But why do you say that current probA and probB intializations should fail? Both are less than 1 and probaA<probB

Comment: The alternative solution, I am thinking of is to write a unit-test which simply does these checkings in runtime. Anything better than that?

Comment: Oh, I keep getting confused by the assertion logic :) -- well it seems that those initializations are more complex in your code, otherwise you wouldn't need those assertions. That's where I'd look for another solution.

Comment: You are right. I do not absolutely need those static assertions. I'll go write some unit tests instead. Do you mind writing an answer with C++ standard quote so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dyp stated in comment, floating-point type variables cannot be used in constant expression. A possible workaround would be to use rational number.

`std::ratio` is C++11 but can easily be ported to C++03

```
template<typename Scalar>
class ProbModel {
public:

    static Scalar getProbA() { return Scalar(probA::num) / probA::den; }
    static Scalar getProbB() { return Scalar(probB::num) / probB::den; }

private:
    typedef std::ratio<3, 10> probA; // 0.3
    typedef std::ratio<6, 10> probB; // 0.6

    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(probA::num < probA::den, "Weird Parameter");
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(probB::num < probB::den, "Weird Parameter");
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(probA::num * probB::den < probB::num * probA::den, "Weird Parameter");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is [Boost Ratio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/ratio.html) for C++03